# simulation the summit rover in ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,
i want to simulate the summitxl robot in ros, but i have some problems:
nico@nico:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/summit_xl_sim$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['summit_xl_sim']             
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['summit_xl_sim']                           
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/nico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121111-114541
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['summit_xl_sim'] to:
['summit_xl_odometry', 'robotnik_worlds', 'summit_xl_description', 'summit_xl_sbpl_nav', 'summit_xl_joystick', 'summit_xl_tf', 'summit_xl_ctrl', 'explore_stage', 'explore', 'summit_xl_2dnav']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> summit_xl_joystick [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_hardware_interface [ make ]                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_hardware_interface
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_mechanism_model [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_mechanism_model ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_mechanism_model
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_controller_interface [ make ]                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_controller_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_controller_interface
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> summit_xl_ctrl [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< summit_xl_joystick [PASS] [ 0.60 seconds ]             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> summit_xl_description [ make ]                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< summit_xl_description [PASS] [ 0.09 seconds ]          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sbpl [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< summit_xl_ctrl [PASS] [ 0.67 seconds ]                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> summit_xl_odometry [ make ]                            
[ rosmake ] All 2 linessbpl: 0.1 sec ] [ summit_x... [ 2 Active 33/72 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir: 无法创建目录"build": 权限不够
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sbpl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/nico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121111-114541/sbpl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sbpl [FAIL] [ 0.13 seconds ]                           
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sbpl. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< summit_xl_odometry [PASS] [ 0.41 seconds ]             
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 35 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/nico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121111-114541              
nico@nico:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/summit_xl_sim$
Then i tried the command "sudo" or chomd etc to change the permission, but the results was the same.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47962/simulation-the-summit-rover-in-ros?/) by [nicole](https://answers.ros.org/users/3538/nicole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i solved the problem, but the new problem comes. I start a empty gazebo, and want to join in the summit xl.urdf to simulate the rover in gazebo. Here are the results:
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1352786299.252684294, 0.039000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1352786299.359426427, 0.733000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
LightListWidget::OnLightMsg
Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:291] DEPRECATED GAZEBO MODEL FILE
On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported
Convert your files using the gzsdf command line tool
You have been warned!

Error [MeshManager.cc:84] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/nico/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/summit_xl_sim/summit_xl_description/meshes/summit_xl_chassis_cam1.mesh]
Exception [Visual.cc:1427] Unable to create a mesh from /home/nico/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/summit_xl_sim/summit_xl_description/meshes/summit_xl_chassis_cam1.mesh

Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
[ INFO] [1352786313.653385039, 378.361000000]: Laser plugin missing , defaults to 101
[ INFO] [1352786313.654083521, 378.361000000]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin should set minimum intensity to 101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
Error [Plugin.hh:101] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_time.so: libgazebo_ros_time.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dbg plugin model name: summit_xl
[ INFO] [1352786313.695041100, 378.361000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1352786313.697636475, 378.361000000]: Callback thread id=0xa76ad2c0
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: 行 2: 11049 已放弃               (核心已转储) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 11046, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/nico/.ros/log/eb4b8668-2d55-11e2-8cc9-001f3c927c3f/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/nico/.ros/log/eb4b8668-2d55-11e2-8cc9-001f3c927c3f/gazebo_gui-2*.log
[ INFO] [1352786314.073681990, 378.361000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to /default_imu
[ INFO] [1352786314.074214530, 378.361000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to 0s
[ INFO] [1352786314.074499971, 378.361000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to 0s
Error [MeshManager.cc:84] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/nico/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/summit_xl_sim/summit_xl_description/meshes/summit_xl_chassis_cam1.mesh]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 11039, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/nico/.ros/log/eb4b8668-2d55-11e2-8cc9-001f3c927c3f/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/nico/.ros/log/eb4b8668-2d55-11e2-8cc9-001f3c927c3f/gazebo-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
anybody can help me, thank you.
nico

---

Originally posted by [nicole](https://answers.ros.org/users/3538/nicole/) with karma: 16 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0